# What is the best way to open and read an excel file from a Flex Application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, flex4.5

What is the best way to open and parse and excel file from a Flex Application built using Adobe Flash Builder 4.5. I have done tons of research, most lead me to external libraries, I could deal with that if that is the best approach, but prefer a built in method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no "built-in method" to read Excel files in Flash. If you've found some libraries that claim to do it, give them a shot; you *really* don't want to try doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this library.
http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/

Comment: There's also a (newer?) fork of as3xls that I used a few months ago - https://github.com/djw/as3xls/. Both work decently for reading, neither of them are acceptable for writing anything complex.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried to use the library but couldn't manage to make it work even for reading, I am thinking of sending the excel file to a webservice to parse and return the result back to the client

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option, it may be simpler to export the Excel file as a .CSV and then load and parse that. It's a much simpler file format, and if your Excel sheet contains simple data it is going to be much easier to do.

Otherwise the library that rejo mentioned (http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/) will help. Excel is a complicated file format, it's best not to go it alone.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but unfortunatley that's not an option